# atk4 schema generator error

Tags: php, atk4

I get the following error when running:

```
class page_generator extends  Page_SchemaGenerator   {

}
```

Application Error: requires jQuery or jUI support

BaseException, code: 0

C:\projects\wamp\atk4\atk4\lib\Form\Submit.php:33

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get such class? What version of ATK4 are you using?
Anyway, you have to add jUI class iun your Frontend class.

Sorry, but I couldn't remain silent and will say that - schema generators are evil !!! :)

There are only very rare case when they are OK. One of such cases is if you actually require dynamically changeable DB structure. If that's the case, then better use this add-on: https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/tree/master/dynamic_model

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your lib/Frontend.php

```
$this->add('jUI');
```

And as @DarkSide said - schema generators are evil.

There is also on-the-fly generator controller for model:

https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/tree/master/dynamic_model